# Compiling C# code from the command line gives error

Tags: c#

I am following this tutorial:

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson01.aspx

I pasted this into a text file, named it Welcome.cs:

```
// Namespace Declaration
using System;

// Program start class
class WelcomeCSS
{
    // Main begins program execution.
    static void Main()
    {
        // Write to console
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the C# Station Tutorial!"); 
    }
}
```

Then I went into the command prompt, and pointed to the file's directory. I typed `csc.exe Welcome.cs` and got this error message:

```
csc.exe is not recognized as internal or external command
```

I am using Visual Studio 2008

I tried moving csc.exe to the Windows directory, and now I am getting this error:

```
fatal error cs2018: unable to find messages file 'cscompui.dll'
```

How can I compile my C# code from the command line?

Comment: FYI... You shouldn't move csc.exe to the windows folder.  It has too many dependencies that it won't be able to find.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

csc.exe isn't in your path.  Try fully-qualifying it:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe
```

(replace 3.5 with whatever framework you're using, of course.)

Note that Visual Studio isn't being used here.  Doesn't matter what version of that you're using, because you're not using it when you compile from the command line.  The command line compiler is part of the framework itself.

Comment: or use the Visual Studio Command Prompt item from the Start Menu in Microsoft VS 2010\ VS Tools

Comment: @Gishu: That's another way to go, sure.  There are multiple answers to this one.  It's probably good for him to know where that executable is, though.  Especially if he ever tries to script compilation of something in a batch file.  Or if he wants to compile on a machine that doesn't have Visual Studio.

Comment: Additionally you can add that folder to your path using the command line: `path=%path%;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5` but that is only for the session duration. To permanently add it to the path, modify your environment variables (under the system control panel). But all this may be more info than you wanted. :)

Comment: @JYelton: More than he wanted, perhaps, but definitely good to note here for anybody who finds this question later :)

Answer (score 7):

You're probably running cmd (Windows command prompt) instead of the [Visual Studio Command Prompt](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rmcochran/commandpromptinstudiotoolsmenu01152008103357am/commandpromptinstudiotoolsmenu.aspx) which is available in the Visual Studio Tools folder.

Look at folder:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008\Visual Studio Tools

Answer (score 5):

This is most likely because the directory containing csc.exe is not in your path, given you're simply running the standard Windows command prompt.

Visual Studio 2008 (as all versions) comes with its own command prompt. This is essentially cmd.exe with some set up scripts that make all the Visual Studio tools accessible (puts the relevant directories in your path, for a start).

The console is easily accessible via the Start menu and should be called **Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt** (under the *Visual Studio Tools* folder).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to use `CSC.exe` and other framework tools from anywhere on the command line go add these to your Path environment variable.

... Depending on framework version and if you have the Windows SDK installed these may be slightly different.  (Also if you are on a 64bit system that would be different as well)

- c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
- C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;
- c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727;
- c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin;

Answer (score 1):

To enable command line invocation of compiler program *csc.exe* of the Microsoft .NET Framework, ***add this to the end of your PATH environment variable.***

Right-click on **"My Computer**" to select Properties.

Click the "**Advanced**" tab.
Click the "**Environment Variable**" button.
Scroll down the "**System variables**" list to the "**Path**" variable.
Double click on "**Path**"
Press the "**End**" key
Type (beginning with a semicolon separator)

```
;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

(be sure to match the right version of Framework from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework`)

Click "**OK**"
Click "**OK**" to close the System Properties window.

*Verify the change:*

open CMD and Type a command such as "csc"
you'll get something like this

> C:\Users\Jerry\Documents\coding>csc
>    Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler
>   version 4.0.30319.33440 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5 Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Comment: I found this answer useful so I create a powershell script to integrate it with vagrant, https://gist.github.com/javier-lopez/449c97c7d07ffcf44cde67992b6a3f1b

Answer (score 0):

A few options:
1) use the "Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt" that is in your Visual Studio Tools folder. This loads up the command prompt with the pathing set correctly so it recognizes the tool name.

2) bypass this, and "Rebuild Solution" from the Build Menu. your bin directory should then have your exe in it.

Comment: i dont have a BUILD menu since it is just a cs file

Comment: You mention VS 2008 in your question so I assume your using Visual Studio 2008.